# How to set a width in percent with maximum width in dp?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have an `ImageView` that needs to stretch with screen width. But I do not want the view to stretch indefinitely. I also need to keep the ratio of the image to 16:9. I am having a hard time to set a maximum width when using percentage in `ConstraintLayout`. I found the ratio can be set using ConstraintLayout, but it is not required to use this layout as long as the ratio will be preserved (note that I cannot use a 3rd party library other than Glide). Here is what I have now.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:9"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/list_item_title"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_max="163dp"
        tools:src="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/list_item_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Test Title" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Without the `app:layout_constraintWidth_max` everything is working fine, but once that attribute is set, the percentage stops working at all and width is set to some arbitrary value (definitely not the 163dp I used). But the fun part is that if the max width is higher than the half of the screen width, the percentage is working again. It seems like those two attributes cannot work together, but I do not know how else to define what I need to do.

Comment: why don't you use maxWidth? like this `android:maxWidth="163dp"`

Comment: I tried that, but it does not seem to be working. When I keep decreasing the value, nothing happens.

Comment: try this                             app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W,16:9"

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without constraint layout you can use LinearLayout or RelativeLayout, Set Image Width to match parent and scale your image to

[image]

Link for details:
https://thoughtbot.com/blog/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide

Comment: I forgot to mention that I need the ratio of the image to be 16:9, I am sorry. I will edit the question.

Comment: This solution is without ConstraintLayouts.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a solution as it does not keep the 16:9 ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it seems like combining `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"` and `app:layout_constraintWidth_max` together does not allow to produce the expected result. A workaround for this would be to use a `Guideline` to constrain the `ImageView` with the desired percentage. You can then constrain the start of the `TextView` to the `Guideline` as well or to the end of the `ImageView`, depending on what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:9"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_max="163dp"
            tools:src="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/list_item_image"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Test Title" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```